# looking for book alien romance

Tags: story-identification

I can't seem to find a book that I read before. All I can recall is that a bunch of humans (men and women) we abducted and were being auctioned on another planet. but for some reason one woman was taken into another room where there were 2 sets of men.

One man from each set came up individually and if she reacted to them and basically started rubbing against them then she was their fated mate.

She gets taken back to their home and later tries to escape to and find her male friend who was sold on the auction block that day.

Anyone know what book this is?

Comment: Was this porn/adult fic? I ask in all seriousness, because searching for these sorts of themes chucks up all sorts of [odd works](https://www.amazon.com/Alien-Romance-Auctioned-Abduction-Protectors-ebook/dp/B01CM0PTSS)

Comment: [Slave girl of Gor](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/432523.Slave_Girl_of_Gor)?

Comment: Same book described? http://www.sffworld.com/forum/threads/cheap-racy-sci-fi-woman-abducted-by-aliens-and-enslaved-on-another-world.18901/